# Nodemon infinite restarting due to changes on my terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

I tried to create a server with express (but this is also happening with HTTP). I'm having some issues with Nodemon, there's a "restarting due to changes" loop

Can someone help me, please?

I'm using 64 bits Windows 8 laptop

```
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 1035;


app.get('/home',(req,res)=>{
    console.log('home')
    res.end('<h1>home page<h1>')
})
app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`Listening at port ${port}`)
})
```

JSON:

```
{
  "name": "node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "newnode.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon newnode.js",
    "dev": "nodemon -L"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "consign": "^0.1.6",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "node": "^14.21.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
}
```

I tried to change the user's variable, also tried to use the old version 2.0.7 of nodemon, but none of these worked.

Node version: v18.12.0
Nodemon version:2.0.20

Comment: You can try to use nodemon `--verbose` flag to get some additional logs from it. Also, any other symptoms you found? Checked [github](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1882) issues? Anyway it is hard to help with environment-related issues. Try changing node version, with deleting and re-installing of the node_modules, continue playing with nodemon versions also. [nvm](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) will help you a bit with that. Also, when asking questions like that - please specify nodejs version and package.json content (or the versions of the libs related to your issue)

Comment: We'll need to know what command you use to start nodemon.

Comment: Why are you requiring `path` in your repro? (It's not used in your example.)  Can you remove it and try again?  I ask because having `path` in there it suggests to me that you are running code that's _different_ from what you posted in your question, possibly because you're using `path` to write a file to your local filesystem, which triggers nodemon because it sees a local file has changed, and restarts the app.

Comment: @Wyck i'm a begginner so i was learning how to use `fs` and `path` and when i was going to learn `express` i just forgot to remove the `path` sorry lol

Comment: @Tom i'm using "start": "nodemon newnode.js" and at some point i used "dev": "nodemon -L"

Answer (score 0):

Interesting topic, about to set up a server :)

From https://www.npmjs.com/package//nodemon#ignoring-files:

> By default, nodemon will only restart when a . js JavaScript file changes. In some cases, you will want to ignore some specific files, directories, or file patterns, to prevent nodemon from prematurely restarting your application.

There's also a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1452) that suggests a similar action to resolve the restart issue.

This [blog post](https://brianchildress.co/prevent-nodemon-from-constantly-restarting/) also suggests ignoring some files.